# How to prevent child in IndexedStack get rebuilt?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `IndexedStack` with 4 children, as 4 tabs that can be changed. All other 3 simple ones are working well, however the 4th child is getting rebuilt if switching to it. How to prevent this?

The child is a custom `StatefulWidget` (let's call it A) that builds a `FutureBuilder`. If the data is fetched from online successfully then it returns another customized `StatfulWidget` (let's call it B). B also had a `FutureBuilder`, and ultimately returns something that basically is a `NestedScrollView` within a `Scaffold`, and has it's own tabviews.

I want the scroll position of it keeping where it is when switching between the tabs. What could be the potential reason? BTW I've tried adding `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to my customized `StatefulWidget`, still the same.

Codes that might helps:
Widget A:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: MainMgr.instance.isLoggedIn(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Text(snapshot.error);
          else {
            if (snapshot.data)
              return Stack(
                children: [
                  UserProfile(
                    MainMgr.instance.selfCOUserID,
                    null,
                    showBackButton: false,
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 60,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('Log out'),
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 29, 161, 242),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await MainMgr.instance.logout();
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            else
              return LoginSignupPage();
          }
        } else
          return Container();
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you post the code of your 4th child?

Comment: is `initState()` called each time you switch to the 4th child?

Comment: @Henok The whole child is just too complex to simplify, it's almost 30% of my app codes. Very difficult to simplify it. So I described my structure in the question trying to find any potential reasons might be from pros with more experience than me.

Comment: I just wanted to see how you stored your future inside FutureBuilder, comment it here if you can

Comment: @pskink The `initState()` of the child itself is not getting called each time. But the `initState()` of the inner child(B) is getting called over and over again.

Comment: so initialize your `Future` once in that `initState` - from what you said above i have an impression that you call it inside `build()` method

Comment: can you please comment FutureBuilder( future : ........) ? only the future part ?

Comment: @Henok Thank you. I added them into the question description.

Comment: It's the `initState()` of `UserProfile` getting called each time.

Comment: `build()` method cannot have any side effects - you need to initialize your `Future` inside `initState`

Comment: @pskink, thank you. but how I'm not sure how to implement that. Can you show me an example with a simple `FutureBuilder` please?

Comment: you have the code in the answer below

Comment: @pskink Thanks a lot! I'll test it and get back here.

Comment: read https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html, the second paragraph reads: *"The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateConfig, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted."*

Comment: Oh my god, thank you both sooooo much. Both of you have saved my day! You saved my months actually. All my `FutureBuilders` are used in the wrong way. No wonder I've always felt something not right, cause I used them a lot. I'll fixes all of them in my app. Thanks again for your help!!!! @pskink @Henok

Comment: the lesson learnt is: always read official documentation first ;-)

Comment: Absolutely right! I thought it might be the `IndexedStack ` or `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` or even `NestedScrollView `. So just checked their documentations. Glad you showed me the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  //below your class's state
  Future future; 


  //inside your init state add
  future = MainMgr.instance.isLoggedIn();


  //inside your FutureBuilder 
  return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: future,//here is whats important
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return Center(child: Cir
      //rest of the code
```

Comment: Oh! This is how you should use `FutureBuilder`, I got them all wrong. Thank you, let me try this in my app.

Comment: yes as @pskink also suggested initializing your future inside init state is the way.