# How to fetch network data on provider context change in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-state

I have a Flutter application with some kinda weird functionality, but it's required one. The application has BottomNavigationBar with pages wrapped in IndexedStack, so that if you go to other page of this IndexedStack, the pages do not reload and stay persistent.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
//...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: selectedIndex,
        children: bottomBarPages(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: navItems,
        currentIndex: selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onNavItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

One of these pages is a ProfilePage, where you can choose between list of users. I use ChangeNotifier that looks like this:

```
class MainUserInfo extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<UserInfo> _users;
  UserInfo _chosenUser;
  //... some get/set/etc methods here
}
```

One of other BottomNavigationBar pages TheOtherPage depends on the chosen user (_chosenUser), on initState it loads data from the Net:

```
class TheOtherPage extends StatefulWidget {
//...

  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAccountData();
  }

  void getAccountData() async {
    //some fetch happening here
    
    setState(() {
      model = response.data;
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

The thing is that after field _chosenUser changes, I need TheOtherPage to load data of chosen user from the Net. But I don't know how to handle it. If I use context.read or context.select it surely tracks changing _chosenUser, but doesn't fetch data of newly chosen one:

```
var mainUserInfo = context.read<MainUserInfo>();
//or
var chosenUser = context.select<MainUserInfo, UserInfo>((userInfo) => userInfo.chosenUser);
```

And I don't wanna save data needed for TheOtherPage in UserInfo object, because there are just too much data, and loading so much data for every user in MainUserInfo._users is not an option.
Also I would to be able to keep track of loading state, because using "bool Isloading" I can show some fancy placeholders while required data is being fetched.

So the general question is how to make TheOtherPage fetch data on changing field of ChangeNotifier on ProfilePage. Maybe my whole approach is bad and I don't need to use Provider and ChangeNotifier here, I would like to see any suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case that provider try to solve: share data between 2 widgets

Here is your tree structure:

```
Scaffold
 \ IndexedStack
    \ ProfilePage  <- share MainUserInfo 
    \ TheOtherPage  <- share MainUserInfo
```

The problem is that you want TheOtherPage to listen to `MainUserInfo` which it doesn't. (Because the `initState()` in a statefulwidget will be called only once, even the state is changed)

I suggest you can listen to the provider inside the `build` method and use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to handle the loading state:

```
class _TheOtherPageState extends State<TheOtherPage> {
//...

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // do nothing here
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {      
    // rebuild everytime the MainUserInfo get notified by watching it
    // final mainUserInfo = context.watch<MainUserInfo>();

    // rebuild everytime the chosenUser change inside MainUserInfo
    final chosenUser = context.select<MainUserInfo, UserInfo>((userInfo) => userInfo.chosenUser);

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getAccountData(chosenUser).
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData){
          model = snapshot.data;

          // return a page with the model
        } else {

          // return the loading placeholders 
        }
      }
    );
  }

  Future getAccountData(user) async {
    //some fetch happening here with the user
    // ...

    return response.data;
  }
}
```

There is one more thing you can try: use `const` keyword
([How to deal with unwanted widget build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build))

```
  ...
  body: IndexedStack(
    index: selectedIndex,
    children: [
      ProfilePage(),
      const TheOtherPage(),    // here
    ],
  ),
  ...

class TheOtherPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TheOtherPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);   // and here

  @override
  _TheOtherPageState createState() => _TheOtherPageState();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. There's a problem with that approach, that TheOtherPage is not persistent is IndexedStack anymore: everytime I click on corresponding BottomBar button, TheOtherPage fetches data again

Comment: Does your BottomBar button change any value inside `MainUserInfo`? If you only want to listen to a specific value change inside `MainUserInfo`, you can use `context.select` instead.

Comment: Does TheOtherPage show the information of the `chosenUser` only? I updated the answer.

Comment: I use `context.select` for `chosenUser` already. The problem is not in the provider methods, I believe `FutureBuilder` somehow breaks `IndexedStack`. I just press on the button of `BottomNavigationBar` and `TheOtherPage` rebuilds and fetches data

Comment: According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63965437/how-to-prevent-child-in-indexedstack-get-rebuilt) the `Future` object must be initialized outside of the `build` method, but to have it rebuilded on `Provider context` change one needs to have it inside. Sounds like a conflict, heh

Comment: I think my structure is fine but I forgot to add `const` keyword. Please check my update~

Comment: Thank you! That saves the day. I didn't used `const` before, so my bad actually, gotta place `const` more often now